# Classifying free symbols from expressions

Tags: python, sympy

Suppose I am given two Symbol objects, `f` and `g`, which I can reasonably assume represent functions. I don't know a priori what these two functions are, but say that without my knowledge, `g` was defined like so:

```
g = symbols('1')
```

where the user has neglected to specify `cls=Number` so that `g.free_symbols` gives me `set([1])` (maybe the user isn't intimately familiar with SymPy). If I collect all the free symbols of `f` and `g` in a set, and then attempt to compute their Jacobian, I end up with an extra column in the matrix representing the derivatives of `f` and `g` with respect to 1, which is nonsense.

How can I detect numbers as Symbol objects which are not explicitly declared to be numbers so as to avoid such a scenario?

Comment: It's probably a bad idea to use `symbols(cls=Number)`. `symbols` is really only meant to be used to create Symbol or Symbol-like objects.

Comment: My point was that I'm expecting users of my class to learn just enough SymPy that they'll be making mistakes like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more targeted approach would use replace:

Target only Numbers

```
>>> eq.replace(
... lambda x: x.is_Symbol and S(x.name).is_Number,
... lambda x: S(x.name))
x + 1
>>> _.atoms(Number)
set([1])
```

Target any number expression

```
>>> Symbol('1+2').replace(
... lambda x: x.is_Symbol and S(x.name).is_Number,
... lambda x: S(x.name))
3
```

Target any expression

```
>>> Symbol('1+x').replace(
... lambda x: S(x.name).is_Symbol is False,
... lambda x: S(x.name))
x + 1
```

Comment: This should also allow me to handle numeric types by wrapping them in `str`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the str of the expression through sympify:

```
>>> eq = Symbol('x') + Symbol('1')
>>> eq.atoms(Number)
set([])
>>> sympify(str(eq))
x + 1
>>> _.atoms(Number)
set([1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could inspect the name of each symbol and see if it looks like a number:

```
import sympy as sp
import re

x = sp.Symbol('x')
g = sp.Symbol('2')
f = x + 1
h = f + g

for s in h.free_symbols:
  print "s = ", s, bool(re.match('^[0-9]+$', str(s)))
```

Output:

```
s =  x False
s =  2 True       -- looks like a number
```

Perhaps, then, you want to substitute numeric values back for those symbols to eliminate them.

```
def eliminate_numbers(f):
  for s in f.free_symbols:
    assigns = {}
    if re.match('^-?[0-9]+$', str(s)):
      assigns[s] = int( str(s) )
  return f.subs(assigns)

print eliminate_numbers(h)
```

Output:

```
x + 3
```